# getJSON loses the controller in the path on second request

Tags: c#, json, web, model-view-controller, getjson

I have a getJSON that loads a DDL from another.
But the first time its loaded, it does it well. When I make a submit on the page, at the console I get error 404 on the getJSON and when I double click it, it sends me the getJSON but without the controller
Visual Explanation:

**Function:**

```
function showPuestoEdit(val, index) {
$.getJSON("GetPuestosCargaJSON" + "?value=" + val, function (result) {
    // Cleans the DDL first
    $("#ddlPuesto").empty();
    var data = result.data;

    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        $("#ddlPuesto").append("<option value=" + data[i].id_puesto + ">" + data[i].nombre + "</option>")
    }
    // This is in order to set the second ddl in the correct position
    $("#ddlPuesto").val(index);
}); }
```

**My CONTROLLER [Usuario]:**

```
    public JsonResult GetPuestosCargaJSON(int? value)
    {
        // Carga los puestos dependiendo del departamento
        List<Puesto> list = repo.GetReaderFromStringToList<Puesto>("SOME SELECT * FROM QUERY HERE where some_id = " + value);
        return Json(new { data = list }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

**The first request in the console:**

```
http://localhost:10994/Usuario/GetMunicipiosCargaJSON?value=17
```

But when I submit some info and I want to try it again the request is :

```
http://localhost:10994/GetMunicipiosCargaJSON?value=17
```

In the path before the Action the Controller disappears, so error 404

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved:
On the submit I had:

```
return RedirectToAction("Index");
```

and now:

```
return new RedirectResult("Index");
```